# Inserting element in ancestor node in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to insert a element in an ancestor element if a condition is true in descendant element.Like in below xml i want to insert a new element "blue" inside "part" element which is the value of descendant element "patternCode".The element should only be inserted if both "patternCode" elements have same value "blue" 
Note :There are 2 patternCode elements in xml which should be compared

```
<Request >
    <Part>
        <Lines>
            <Entry>
                <entity>
                    <Cover>
                        <Entry>
                            <Terms>
                                <Entry>
                                    <DisplayValue/>
                                    <PatternCode>Blue</PatternCode>
                                    <ValueTypeName>bit</ValueTypeName>
                                </Entry>
                            </Terms>
                            <Pattern>
                                <Description>white</Description>
                                <Name>white</Name>
                            </Pattern>
                            <PatternCode>Blue</PatternCode>
                            <PublicID>pc</PublicID>
                        </Entry>
                    </Cover>
                    <Locations>
                        <!-- other data-->
                    </Locations>
                </entity>
            </Entry>
        </Lines>
    </Part>
</Request>
```

Expected Output

```
<Request >
    <Part>
     <Blue>  <Blue>
        <Lines>
            <Entry>
                <entity>
                    <Cover>
                        <Entry>
                            <Terms>
                                <Entry>
                                    <DisplayValue/>
                                    <PatternCode>Blue</PatternCode>
                                    <ValueTypeName>bit</ValueTypeName>
                                </Entry>
                            </Terms>
                            <Pattern>
                                <Description>white</Description>
                                <Name>white</Name>
                            </Pattern>
                            <PatternCode>Blue</PatternCode>
                            <PublicID>pc</PublicID>
                        </Entry>
                    </Cover>
                    <Locations>
                        <!-- other data-->
                    </Locations>
                </entity>
            </Entry>
        </Lines>
    </Part>
</Request>
```

What i tried

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="Request/Part/Lines/Entry/entity/Cover" >
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:for-each select="Entry">
            <xsl:copy>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="x">
        <xsl:value-of select="PatternCode"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="Terms/Entry">           
           <xsl:variable name="y">
            <xsl:value-of select="PatternCode"/>
              </xsl:variable>
                   <xsl:if test="$x=$y">
                      <xsl:call-template name="compute" >
                               <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$y"/>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                   </xsl:if>
               </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="compute" >
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="Part">
         <xsl:element name="{$value}"></xsl:element> 
    <xsl:for-each >                 
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you please post the XSLT you've tried. And please mention the XSLT version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You should approach this the other way round:

```
<template match="part">
 <xsl:if test="descendant::cover/entry/terms/entry/patterncode = descendant::cover/entry/patterncode"> 
insert the <blue> node here
```

It's much easier to modify the element you're currently working with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do:

**XSLT1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Part">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:if test="count(.//PatterCode) = count(.//PatterCode[. = (current()//PatternCode)[1]])">
                <Blue/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I think XSLT2.0 would make it even easier and efficient:

**XSLT2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Part[count(.//PatterCode) = count(.//PatterCode[. = (current()//PatternCode)[1]])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <Blue/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```